# How to use promise with async await by using ngOnInint in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an application which is developed in Angular 14.

My service/API request calls are served through subscribe which was fine in old logic.

Now we have some changes and we need to implement duplication check before the call to API/service and after getting the response from the API, we need to add this object in an array so that duplications can be checked before the call to an API.

I tried to change the API call from subscribe to return a Promise by using toPromise and using with async await but the behaviour of getting a response from API call is same.

This doesn't was work as I expected but same approach work is JavaScript and ReactJs.  Why not in Angular?

```
async ngOnInit()
let resultSpi:MedicationPermissionModel = this.spiPerList && this.spiPerList.length > 0 ?this.spiPerList.find((x) => x.ProviderSpi && x.ProviderSpi.indexOf(this.medication.ProviderSpi) > -1):undefined;

if(!resultSpi) 
 let response:any=await getProviderServiceLevelToPromise(this.medication.ProviderSpi)
this.spiPerList.push(response)
}
```

This is a very simple task but Angular is not letting me achieve this.

Both check for duplication and the response to add in array works separately rather working in a sequence flow, it behaves differently.  Getting the response from API is not in a single call while I am debugging the flow. Once the response is received then
Control doesn't  go up and check for the duplication.

And there are multiple calls of this component and each one have a medication record.

How can I fix the issue? I am a new user to Angular.

Comment: are you missing `await` at line `getProviderServiceLevelToPromise` there?

Comment: No,  sorry I forgot to mention await here. But the issue is same with await. See now I have corrected in my post.  Please guide now

Comment: What is `getProviderServiceLevelToPromise`?

Comment: Its a HTTP client post request which return a promise by using pipe, map and toPromise

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post a [mcve]. Maybe the problem is in that function.

Comment: OK I try to add the minimum reproducible till working day

Answer (score -1):

you missed "await"

```
async ngOnInit(){
    let resultSpi:MedicationPermissionModel = this.spiPerList && this.spiPerList.length > 0 ?this.spiPerList.find((x) => x.ProviderSpi && x.ProviderSpi.indexOf(this.medication.ProviderSpi) > -1):undefined;
    
    if(!resultSpi)   let response:any= await getProviderServiceLevelToPromise(this.medication.ProviderSpi);
    this.spiPerList.push(response);
}
```